# mongoose query to find if startDate and endDate is intersecting with any object from array of startDates and endDates objects

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm trying to find if a specific startDate and endDate is overlapping with any of the date objects in mongoDb.

Here's the data in db
[image]

Please note this is an array of objects.

now I've something date like this

```
init Date >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 2023-03-23T04:03:49.642Z

Ending Date >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 2023-04-10T04:03:49.642Z
```

Now I need to return this document if it's overlapping else return nothing.

Here's what I been trying to do;

```
  const getAvailabilityDetails = await Products.find({
    _id: pid,
    bookings: {
      $elemMatch: {
        // $and: [
          productBookingStartDate: { $lt: new Date(initDate.toString()).toISOString() },
          productBookingCompleteDate: { $gt: endingDayBufferCalcWithContractDays }
        // ]
      }
    }
  });
```

It's not working at any case. In debug query I'm getting something like this.

```
Mongoose: products.find({ _id: ObjectId("63de4823561e0319a5745537"), bookings: { '$elemMatch': { productBookingStartDate: { '$lt': new Date("Thu, 23 Mar 2023 04:03:49 GMT") }, productBookingCompleteDate: { '$gt': new Date("Mon, 10 Apr 2023 04:03:49 GMT") } } }}, { projection: {} })
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking overlap between time range `a`->`b` and time range `c`->`d` we need to accept 4 options: [`acdb`, `cabd`, `cadb`, `acbd`] and reject two options: [`abcd`, `cdab`], So we want to find cases where `c` < `b` and `d` > `a`:

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: pid,
  bookings: {
    $elemMatch: {
      productBookingCompleteDate: {$gt: new Date(initDate)},
      productBookingStartDate: {$lt: new Date(endDate)}
    }
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/s7V0i3DlGVL)